# Assigning array of objects into an interface based array

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript

I have this problem on assigning an array of objects to an interface based array

Currently I have this implementation on my interface item.ts

```
export interface IItem {
    id: number, text: string, members: any
}
```

and on the item.component.ts

```
export class ItemComponent {
    selectedItems: IItem[] = [];
    items: IExamItems;
    getSelected(): void {
        this.selectedItems = this.items.examItems.map(examItem=> examItem.item)
    }
}
```

it seems that i'm always getting this error

```
TS2322: Type 'IItem[][]' is not assignable to type 'IItem[]'.
Type 'IItem[]' is not assignable to type 'IItem'.
Property 'id' is missing in type 'IItem[]'.
```

Comment: We are yet missing `IExamItems` interface declaration

Comment: Yes definitely include the interface

Comment: Greg is right. If examItem.item is an IItem then please try a push each item and it should work. Do a console of this.items.examItems.map(examItem=> examItem.item) and you get the structure you are trying to assign. Seems like its a type mismatch

Comment: ah sorry forgot to include, but i've already declared it


@Gary yes, thanks for pointing that out it is indeed a mismatch, and already got the solution as well Thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your assignment doesn't work because as the error states, the value has an incompatible type with the field. You can't assign `IItem[][]` to `IItem[]`, as the former is *an array of arrays* of `IItem` and the latter is just an array of `IItem`. You either need to flatten the array or change the type of `selectedItems` field to `IItem[][]`. If you want to flatten the array, you can use `Array.prototype.concat`:

```
const itemArr = this.items.examItems.map(examItem=> examItem.item);
this.selectedItems = Array.prototype.concat.apply([], itemArr);
```